# how to modify the message using onbeforeunload in chrome

Tags: message, onbeforeunload

I want to use my message like "Are you sure?" when closing the browser.But, the following code do not means.Chrome still given the default tips.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        console.log("test");
        return 'the message I want to use';
}
```

the version of chrome:51.0.2704.106 m. Wish the answers, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Chrome 51, Custom messages in onbeforeunload dialogs was remove, instead, a generic string not under the control of the webpage will be shown.

Read the following link for more detail:

[Custom messages in onbeforeunload dialogs (removed)](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480)